# Seeking a O(nlogn) alg for counting point pairs with coordinates distance greater than certain value

Tags: algorithm

Given a input n points (x_i, y_i), where x_i, y_i \in 1..n \forall i. Can anybody enlighten me with the idea of constructing a O(nlogn) algorithm to count pairs of points (i,j), where |x_i-x_j|>=a && |y_i-y_j|>=b. A nice assumption can be a=b=n/2.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No attempt given, terrible formatting, looks like homework/programming competition.

Comment: I have been traveling around the idea on divide and conquer. I did a lot of try with different types of partition but it didn't ring any bell to me. It is odd that people tend to focus on finding pairs within a certain range or simply the nearest pair. It is still possible to solve this problem from that direction. But I may need some idea on this from different people.

Comment: [this is not the place for getting those](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's try and work out then number of pairs where |x_i-x_j| < a && |y_i-y_j| < b. Sort on the X co-ordinate. Now process the points in that order, and keep a buffer of points where |x_i-x_j| < a. Each point is inserted into that buffer once, and removed from it once. 
Make a binary tree out of the contents of that buffer, ordered on Y co-ordinate, and with counts at each node of the number of points below that node of the tree. So each time you insert a point into that tree you can work out how many points in the buffer are within b of it in the y direction.

Of course just suming the size of the buffer at each insert tells us how many pairs satisfy |x_i-x_j| < a, and a similar process will tell us how many pairs satisfy |y_i-y_j| < b.

Each pair falls into one of four categories, and we now know enough to count them all. We know the size of (X-close and Y-close). We know the size of X-close so we know the size of (X-close but not Y-close). Similarly, we know the size of Y-close so we know the size of (not X-close but Y-close). These are three of the four possible categories and we know that if there are N points there are N*(N-1)/2 pairs, so we can subtract the size of the other three categories to get us the size of (not X-close and not Y-close), which of course is what you asked for.